# How to check table data and input data are equal or not?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to check the input value to text box is created or not in the database after pressing New Button (it will go to `create()` function).

Let's say, the input value is `90112`, if it is created, I want to show the message `item no: is already existed.`.

```
function create()
{
    if ((document.form1.itemcode.value.length == 0 )  || 
        (document.form1.itemcode.value.length <= 5 )
    {
        showMessage("Enter the Fabric Item No ");
        document.form1.itemcode.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

I don't know how to check the table data and input data are equal or not.

Comment: This question is very unclear to me..

Comment: the value from the database can be added as a hidden tag and using javascript compare the new value with existing DB value

Comment: Please note that this is not JSP code. This is JavaScript code. Writing JavaScript code inside a JSP file and having problems with it does not necessarily make it a JSP problem. JSP is merely a HTML/CSS/JS code generator.

Answer (score 1):

Carry the Db Record in the hidden field, and then do this.

```
function checkExist()
                {
                    var dbRecord=document.getElementById("hiddenFieldValue").value;
                    var dbRecord=document.getElementById("inputFieldValue").value;
                    if(dbRecord==dbRecord)
                    {
                        alert("Record already exist");
                    }else{
                        // dosomething
                    }

                }
```